# socketio and redisstore scaling efficiency

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am working on a pretty big project that involves sending data between clients. So, I am just researching on some new technologies out there. Anyways, thought I'd give Nodejs a try. I just have a question about socketio and redis.

When we are using the pub/sub functions in socketio, does every client connection create a new connection to redis? Or, does socketio use a max of create three connections (in total, regardless of the number of clients) to do the pub/sub stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L685-L691), it seems that each client connection has two associated subscriptions to Redis (`this.store` in the code), but that each socket.io server has only three connections to Redis ([source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/stores/redis.js#L63-L84)).

```
this.store.subscribe('message:' + data.id, function (packet) {
  self.onClientMessage(data.id, packet);
});

this.store.subscribe('disconnect:' + data.id, function (reason) {
  self.onClientDisconnect(data.id, reason);
});
```

Redis should be able to handle a lot of connections as well as subscriptions, but benchmarking is recommended as always.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the source code, I just couldn't figure out if the Redis 'Store' object gets created for each client, or whether it is reused. Any ways thank you.